# Is there a way to tokenize two strings and go through the tokens in parallel?

Tags: c, syntax

Is there a way to tokenize two strings and move through the tokens in parallel? (since I have two strings I can't use `strtok(NULL, "bar")` twice)

Also, is there way to make `strtok` to token a string and keep that string untokened?

For example:

```
void foo(char* form, char* num){

    char *templ=form, *tempr=num;
    templ = strtok(templ, " ");//but this tokenize form as well
```

Comment: Depending on platform you might have [`strtok_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html).

Comment: You'll need to make a copy of your original string if you want to keep it.

Comment: Or `strtok_s` if `strtok_r` is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on most platforms there is. You can use `strtok_r`, which is the reentrable version of `strtok` which does not store the state in static memory:

```
char *save1, *save2;
temp1 = strtok_r(templx, " ", &save1);
temp2 = strtok_r(temply, " ", &save2);
```

Note that you should generally use `strtok_r` if it is available, even for parsing a single source of tokens.

If `strtok_r` is not available, you could resort to using `sscanf` and keeping track of the position in the string being tokenized. Depending on the complexity of the tokenization task that you are trying to solve, this could provide a viable solution as well.

Comment: Doing it with `sscanf` we'd have to create a dynamic array with the same size as the one we want to token right? like `sscanf(original, "%s", token);` inside a loop and move up the address of original with `strlen(token)` with each iteration. Note very elegant...

Comment: @kuhaku No, `strlen(token)` isn't the right solution, because it does not account for spaces. You would need to use the `%n` format specifier, like this:  `size_t offset = 0; sscanf(original+offset, "%s%n", token, consumed); offset += consumed;`

Comment: Hmm looks like `%n` is disabled in VS2013, I'll lookup a way to enable it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, once upon a time, the man page for strtok was much more blatant about not using it.  At any rate:

1. strtok_r is the reentrant version; that should allow you to go through the tokens in parallel.
2. As far as I know, it's not possible to have strtok not keep the string untokened; you would want to use strcpy to make a copy of the unmangled version.